# SQL Query to return rows where a column value appears multiple time

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm creating a simple database which will allow me to track snooker results, producing head to head results between players. Currently I have 3 tables: (Player, Fixture, Result)

```
PlayerID    PlayerName
1           Michael Abraham
2           Ben Mullen
3           Mark Crozier

FixtureID   Date                 TableNo    Group
1           07/12/2015 19:00:00  12         0
2           08/12/2015 12:00:00  9          0

ResultID    FixtureID   PlayerID    FramesWon
1           1           1           3
2           1           3           1
3           2           1           5
4           2           2           1
```

I would like a query which returns all rows in the result table for fixtures which took place between players 1 and 3. Currently my query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Result
WHERE PlayerID IN (1,3);
```

This returns the first 3 rows of the result table - when I'm only looking for the top 2 rows because they share the same FixtureID. Is there an easy way to remove the third row from this query result, or should I reconsider my database design? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear why you're `SELECT`ing against `PlayerID` if what you want is rows that "share the same `FixtureID`".  Can you tell us a bit more about what you're functionally trying to accomplish?

Comment: sure - my friends and I play snooker regularly, but now I'm starting to track all results so we can total the 'FramesWon' over certain time periods, e.g. determining who won the most frames in 2015. So if player 1 plays player 2, the details of the fixture are stored in the Fixture table, which links to the Result table. So I need to track results in which player 1 was against player 3, hence I need to query the PlayerID, but where the FixtureID is also the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a GROUP BY query, grouping by FixtureID and counting the rows for each FixtureID. This query will select all FixtureIDs with both players 1 and 3:

```
select
  FixtureID
from
  Results
where
  PlayerID IN (1,3)
group by
  FixtureID
having
  count(*)=2
```

then to get the record from the Results table you can use this query:

```
select *
from Results
where FixtureID IN (
  select FixtureID
  from Results
  where PlayerID IN (1,3)
  group by FixtureID
  having count(*)=2
)
```

Comment: thank you - this is exactly what I was looking to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could join your fixtures table twice, like this:

```
select
  *
from
  Result as R1
  join Result as R2 on R1.FixtureID = R2.FixtureID
where
  R1.PlayerID in (1,3)
  AND R2.PlayerID in (1,3)
  AND R1.PlayerID != R2.PlayerID
group by
  R1.FixtureID
;
```

Or, since it's a bit messy now, show it like a snooker score display often is shown:

```
select
  R1.FixtureID, R1.PlayerID as player1, R1.FramesWon as player1_frames, R1.FramesWon+R2.FramesWon as total_frames, R2.FramesWon as player2_frames, R2.PlayerID as player2
from
  Result as R1
  join Result as R2 on R1.FixtureID = R2.FixtureID
where
  R1.PlayerID in (1,3)
  AND R2.PlayerID in (1,3)
  AND R1.PlayerID != R2.PlayerID
group by
  R1.FixtureID
;
```